# Как получить данные о пикселе файла (.bmp) с помощью GetPixel ()?

Tags: c++, winapi

Как с помощью функции GetPixel получить данные о пикселе файла изображения? Или как сделать хендл не к окну консоли, а к файлу?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что за хендл и откуда он взялся... Разверните вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HBITMAP bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"файл.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HGDIOBJ old = SelectObject(hdc, bmp);

COLORREF pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);

SelectObject(hdc, old);
DeleteDC(hdc);
DeleteObject(bmp);
```